# How to write a CSV file in R

Tags: r, export-to-csv

I am unable to write a to a CSV file in R. I receive two errors. After reviewing other posts I will add that I am an admin on my system. Please can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong. That includes the writing of this post as it is my first. Thank you for your time.

I have set my working directory and received no error:

```
setwd("~/R_Learning_Files/titanic")
```

I checked my working directory:

```
getwd()
"C:/Users/felix/OneDrive/Documents/R_Learning_Files/titanic"
```

My attempt to write to a CSV file:

```
submit_df <- data.frame(passenger_id = rep(892:1309, survived = rf_05_preds))

write.csv(submit_df, file = "rf_sub_2021/07/11_01", row.names = FALSE)
```

The error I have received:

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'rf_sub_2021/07/11_01': No such file or directory
```

Comment: The instruction `submit_df <- data.frame(passenger_id = rep(892:1309, survived = rf_05_preds))` looks very suspicious. Is the column `passenger_id` really defined like that?
Have you noticed that `survived` is not an argument to `rep`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `/` in filenames. Also a csv file should end with `'.csv'`. Try -

```
write.csv(submit_df, file = "rf_sub_2021-07-11_01.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```